# Xubuntu 11.10 won't boot without an attached monitor

Tags: boot, xubuntu, headless

When I detach the monitor from my computer Xubuntu won't boot. If I plug in the monitor after a while I can see it's stuck somewhere (I see a frozen Xubuntu boot screen progress bar)

When I boot with my monitor attached it does boot normally.

Is there a way to get this to work? I read somewhere Xubuntu even *requires* a screen while booting. This is supposed to be a headless server where I can ssh/vnc into.

Btw: no network connections are established either, so I can't ssh into the box.

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem. I require my PC to boot without a monitor, but later if I connect a monitor I should be able to login and get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea would be to remove `lightdm` and the `plymouth*` packages, do a `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot. Other solutions may exist; see other posts tagged [headless](/questions/tagged/headless).

This way, your login window won't come and you can still start the GUI from CLI with `startxfce4` when the need arises.